# How to tell Facebook which div is the "content" one? (for links summary)

Tags: facebook, blogger

I have a small blog hosted on blogger.com

I don't understand why, when people like or share a blog post on Facebook, the real content is *never* fetched as a summary.

For example, for [this post](http://www.forexperimenti.it/2012/11/due-settimane-di-breakon.html), the summary is the small "about me" that I placed on the sidebar, while on [this other post](http://www.forexperiments.com/2012/11/two-weeks-with-breakon.html), the summary is the first comment.

It's weird, what I can do? There is a way, for example a class, to indicate the main content div?

Comment: Links added for clarity and to show the page layout, spam not intended

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Open Graph tags for Facebook into your blog.

Answer (score 0):

Implement opengraph protocol on Blogger. It marks the post title, description, image, author etc using its markup language. Refer this tutorial on [Implement ogp on Blogger](http://www.bloggerhow.com/2012/07/implement-open-graph-in-blogger-blogs.html)

Comment: Please explain more in your post. This would be considered as link only answer.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.